# Parse ACL Not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have set up a user which has an associated role, and an object that has the ACL set to that role.

When i query the objects as that user, i get 0 results.

Am i missing something, or is there a bug?

Thanks.

Also, any pointers on my code would be nice.

```
var Budget = Parse.Object.extend("budget");
    var budget = new Budget();

    var acl = new Parse.ACL();
    acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
    acl.setWriteAccess(Parse.User.current().id, true);
    acl.setReadAccess(Parse.User.current().id, true);
    budget.setACL(acl);

    budget.set("name", 'Test');

    budget.save(null, {
      success: function(budget) {
            var Role = new Parse.ACL();
            Role.setPublicReadAccess(true);
            Role.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
            var role = new Parse.Role(budget.id, Role);
            role.getUsers().add(Parse.User.current());
            role.save(null, {
              success: function(role) {
                    var acl = new Parse.ACL();
                    acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
                    acl.setWriteAccess(budget.id, true);
                    acl.setReadAccess(budget.id, true);
                    budget.setACL(acl);

                    budget.save(null, {
                      success: function(budget) {
                            console.log(budget);
                      },
                      error: function(result, error) {
                        console.log(result, error);
                      }
                    });
              },
              error: function(result, error) {
                console.log(result, error);
              }
            });
      },
      error: function(result, error) {
        console.log(result, error);
      }
    });
```

Comment: You don't actually look to be giving the role any rights over anything. You set the bugs get to be able to access itself only, which makes little sense.

Comment: I am, the ACL for roles is a unique name. I'm setting that name to be the id of the budget - therefore the ACL for the budget needs to be it's own ID.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, i was using acl.setWriteAccess(budget.id, true); but i should have been using acl.setRoleWriteAccess(budget.id, true);

Fixed!